# What doesn't my C++ program work when I try to use recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion, continue

---

I need help with the following c++ code, trying to add a `continue` at the end of the program so that it will make a user specified dimension for rectangle and ask the user to redo the program again.

Compile and ran it without the silly if and else statement at the final part of the program, and it works. But with the `continue` / recursion it failed miserably. lolz. me = noob.

---

```
int main()
{


    int height, width, tmp, tmp2;

    char continue;

    cout << "Please Enter The Height Of A Rectangle (whole numbers only): ";
height:
    cin >> height;
    if(height<1)
    {
        cout << "   Please Enter A Height Of Between 1 And 20: ";
        goto height;
    }
    cout << "Please Enter The Width Of A Rectangle  (whole numbers only): ";
width:
    cin >> width;
    if(width<1)
    {
        cout << "   Please Enter A Width Of Between 1 And 38: ";
        goto width;
    }

    cout << ' ';                                         // Add a space at the start (to neaten top)
    for(tmp=0; tmp!=width; tmp++) cout << "__";          // Top Of Rectangle
    for(tmp=0; tmp!=(height-1); tmp++)
    {
        cout << "\n|";   // Left Side Of Rectangle
        for(tmp2=0; tmp2!=width; tmp2++) cout << "  ";    // Create A Gap Between Sides
        cout << "|";
    }                                  // Right Side Of Rectangle
    cout << "\n|";                                       // Left Side Of Bottom Of Rectangle  to neaten bottom)
    for(tmp=0; tmp!=width; tmp++) cout << "__";          // Bottom Of Rectangle
    cout << '|';                                         // Right Side Of Bottom Of Rectangle (to neaten bottom)

    cout << "Type 'y' if you would like to continue and any other combination to quit.";
continue:
    cin >> continue;
    if(continue == 'y')
    {
        main();
        cout << "\n\n";
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }
    else
        cout << "\n\n";
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know there is proabbly a better way of doing it, i just don't know how to do continues sorry, lol

Comment: (moved in [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221953/noob-programming-help-c/6222004#6222004))

Comment: @Matteo : It's worth acknowledging the difference between 'bad' and 'illegal'. `goto` is usually bad, recursing in `main` is illegal.

Comment: @ildjarn: the truth is that I know that either in C or in C++ it's illegal, but I was too lazy to look up. :)

Comment: @Matteo : Fair enough, but it is indeed C++ where it's illegal. :-]

Comment: Man, this snippet must be in a hall of fame!!

Comment: @Rodrigo: probably the original weird-indented version. :)

Answer (score 5):

`continue` is a keyword in C++, so you cannot have a variable with that name.

Answer (score 5):

You should put your code in a a while loop.

```
int main()
{
    //  declaration of variables here

    do
    {
        // code here

        cout << "Type 'y' if you would like to continue and any other combination to quit.";
        cin >> doYouWantToContinue; // change the keyword!
    }
    while (doYouWantToContinue == 'y');
}
```

Comment: Your test fails to check whether the user entered something in the first place! If you just hit enter, `doYouWantToContinue` will be unchanged (and presumably uninitialized).

Answer (score 4):

In addition to `continue` being a reserved word, it is illegal to call `main` in C++. From the '03 standard, §3.6.1/3:

> The function `main` shall not be used within a program. The linkage of `main` is implementation-defined. A program that declares `main` to be `inline` or `static` is ill-formed. The name `main` is not otherwise reserved. [*Example*: member functions, classes, and enumerations can be called `main`, as can entities in other namespaces. ]

Comment: +1 for mentioning both about `continue` being reserved and the illegality of calling `main`, AND for providing explanation.

Answer (score 3):

continue is used to short-circuit loops, e.g.:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    if (f(i))
    {
        continue; // skip the rest of the loop
    }

    do_something_interesting_with(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

continue is a c++ keyword, use a different name for it

instead of

```
char continue;
```

try

```
char cont;
```

Answer (score 0):

My 2¢: throw away all this stuff, and rewrite it keeping in mind that

1. `goto`s and labels are bad;
2. they should be replaced with loops (probably `do`...`while` in your case);
3. declaring variables/labels with reserved/already used names is bad (and in most cases it's illegal);
4. recursing in `main` is bad (actually, it's illegal according to the standard);
5. good indentation is not optional (even if the compiler won't mind).
6. `#include`s are *not* optional.

And maybe move the user input/validation logic in a separate function to avoid code duplication.